# Can a non-filer dependent claim coronavirus support?

Tags: united-states, taxes, covid-19, stimulus

I didn't file taxes due to my zero income within the last two years. I'm 40 years old. My daughter was claiming me as dependent in 2018, 2019.

This year I got a job. So far I earned $2,000 year to date. I'm not sure I'll be able to cross the $4,000 threshold to get out of my daughter's "dependent list". It may or may not happen this year. So far I only earned $2,000 year to date.

So I'm not sure if I qualify for a corona virus NON_FILER relief. This [IRS link](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/non-filers-enter-payment-info-here) is quite confusing to me. Should I apply or not?  I read this article and it says "you don't qualify if someone claimed you as a dependent". But this year, it is possible for me to cross the $4,000 earnings. So do I qualify or not?

Answer (score 3):

You were claimed as a dependent for 2018 and 2019, so you will not receive the check during 2019. You can still claim the credit when you file for 2020, as long as no one *can* claim you as a dependent. Note that even if someone does not claim you, but they could, you wouldn't be eligible for the check.

In order to ensure that your daughter is not eligible to claim you, you must either provide for more than 50% of your living expenses or earn more than $4,200 in income for 2020. [IRS Publication 501](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p501) has the details. If either of these are true and you still meet the other requirements for the stimulus credit, you will receive the payment after you file for 2020 next year.